# What is this rspec expect block doing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to figure out some Rspec code

We have a double:

```
let(:store_service) { double(StoreService) }
```

Then within an `it` block:

```
expect(store_service).to receive(:run) do
  { error: 'The storeman did not sign up for this.' }
end
```

What is this block doing in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, or why the docs didn't help--what do you mean by "how does it work"? `receive` takes an optional block argument, used as the implementation of the method: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/configuring-responses/block-implementation

Comment: have edited the question to specifically ask what is it doing

Comment: I just explained what it was doing, and so do the linked docs.

Comment: So is it forcing the stubbed method to return a hash with an error?

Comment: Is it? Why not just check? Or change it and see what happens? Or read the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the `allow` and `expect` keywords are mixed up.
[rubocop-rspec](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop-rspec) can help you to avoid this.

For details how to raise and expect errors see the [raising-an-error](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/configuring-responses/raising-an-error) and [raise-error-matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-9/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher) documentation.

An example unit test could look like this:

```rb
describe StoreService do
  context "when storeman did not sign up" do
    subject { StoreService.new(sign_up: nil).run }

    it "raises an error" do
      expect { subject.run }.to raise_error("The storeman did not sign up for this.")
    end
  end
end
```

An example intetegration test could look like this:

```rb
class Caller
  def run
    store_service = build_store_service
    store_service.run
  rescue RuntimeError => e
    handle_error(e)
  end

  def handle_error(e)
     ...
  end

  def build_store_service
    ...
  end
end

describe Caller do
  describe "run" do
    context "when storeman did not sign up" do
      subject(:caller) { described_class.new }

      let(:store_service) { double(StoreService) }
      let(:error_msg) { "The storeman did not sign up for this." }

      before do
        allow(store_service).to receive(:run).and_raise(error_msg)
        allow_any_instance_of(Caller).to receive(:build_store_service).and_return(store_service)
      end

      it "calls run" do
        expect(caller).to receive(:handle_error)
        caller.run
      end
    end
  end
end
```